# Finding the equal of a expression

Tags: analysis

We can write the equal of $\psi_{11}\psi_{11}$ as follows

$\psi_{11}\psi_{11}=\sqrt {2}\psi_{10}+\dfrac{4}{\sqrt{10}}\psi_{12}$

where

$\psi_{10}=\sqrt {2}$

$\psi_{11}=\sqrt {6}(4t-1)$

$\psi_{12}=\dfrac{\sqrt {10}\left( 3\, \left( 4\,t-1 \right) ^{2}-1 \right)}{ 2}$

$\psi_{13}=\dfrac{\sqrt {14}}{2}(5(  4t-1 ) ^{3}-12t+3) $

$\psi_{14}=\dfrac{3\sqrt {2}}{8}\big( {35\, ( 4t-1)  ^{4}}-30( 4t-1) ^{2}+3\big)$

Similary;

$\psi_{12}\psi_{11}= \dfrac{4}{\sqrt{10}}\psi_{11}$.

How can we find the equal of the followings in terms of $\psi_{11}, \psi_{12}$ etc. like above?

$\psi_{13}\psi_{11}=?$

$\psi_{14}\psi_{12}=?$

Comment: What is "the equal" of $\psi_{11}\psi_{11}$?

Comment: Your text is very unclear. Why do you need two indices while the first one is always 1 ? Moreover, in expression $\psi_{12}\psi_{11}= \dfrac{4}{\sqrt{10}}\psi_{11}$, one can simplify by $\psi_{11}$... then...$\psi_{12}= \dfrac{4}{\sqrt{10}}$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your sequence of function $\psi_{1a}(t)$ can be expressed in terms of [Legendre polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_polynomials)

$$\psi_{1a}(t) = \sqrt{2(2a+1)} P_a(4t-1)$$

It is known that 
$$\int_{-1}^1 P_a(x) P_b(x) P_c(x) dx = 2 \begin{pmatrix}a & b & c\\0 & 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}^2$$

where
$\begin{pmatrix}j_1 & j_2 & j_3\\m_1 & m_2 & m_3\end{pmatrix}$  is the [Wigner 3j symbol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3-j_symbol).

Together with the orthogonality relation of Legendre polynomials

$$\int_{-1}^1 P_a(x)P_b(x) dx  =\frac{2}{2a+1} \delta_{ab}$$

One can deduce

$$\psi_{1a}\psi_{1b} = \sum_{c=|a-b|}^{a+b}
\sqrt{2(2a+1)(2b+1)(2c+1)}\begin{pmatrix}a & b & c\\0 & 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}^2 \psi_{1c}$$

For $(a,b) = (1,3)$ and $(a,b) = (2,4)$, this reduces to

$$\begin{align}
\psi_{11}\psi_{13} &= \sqrt{\frac{54}{35}} \psi_{12} + \sqrt{\frac{32}{21}} \psi_{14}\\
\psi_{12}\psi_{14} &= \sqrt{\frac{72}{49}}\psi_{12} + \sqrt{\frac{4000}{5929}}\psi_{14} + \sqrt{\frac{2250}{1573}}\psi_{16}
\end{align}$$

I don't know offhand the formula for general Wigner 3j-symbols. I just ask a CAS to compute the coefficients for me. I remember the formula for $m_1 = m_2 = m_2 = 0$ is not that horrible, you need to dig that out yourself.

**Update**

I found the formula we need from L&L's [Quantum Mechanics](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0750635398) (Chapter XIV, addition of angular momentum). 
After simplification, the formula isn't that bad.

When $2p = a+b+c$ is even, we have

$$\begin{pmatrix}a & b & c\\ 0 & 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}
= (-1)^p \left[\frac{\binom{2u}{u}\binom{2v}{v}\binom{2w}{w}}{(2p+1)\binom{2p}{p}}\right]^{1/2}
\quad\text{ where }\quad
\begin{cases} 2u &= b + c - a \\ 2v &= c + a - b\\ 2w &= a+b - c\end{cases}$$

and the 3j symbols vanish for odd $2p$.

Comment: Thank you very much. Which CAS software? Could you share the code?

Comment: @HD239 I use maxima, after loading the package clebsch_gordan by `load(clebsch_gordan)`,  one can compute the 3j symbols using the function  wigner_3j(j1,j2,j3,m1,m2,m3).

Comment: I wrote a [Maple code][1] for calculating. But there is a wrong something. For 
 example;
In book;

 for $(a,b) = (2,2)$,  
 
we have
\begin{align}
\psi_{12}\psi_{12} &=\sqrt{2}\psi(1, 0)+{\frac {20 \psi
 \left( 1,2 \right) }{7\sqrt{10}}}  
\end{align}

But in my code,


 for $(a,b) = (2,2)$,  
 
I find it as
\begin{align}
\psi_{12}\psi_{12} &=\sqrt{2}\psi(1, 0)+{\frac {20 \psi
 \left( 1,2 \right) }{7\sqrt{10}}} +{\frac {6\sqrt{2} \psi
 \left( 1,4 \right) }{7}} 
\end{align}


  [1]: https://www.mapleprimes.com/view.aspx?sf=255175_Answer/the_last_question.mw

Comment: Your book cannot be correct.  $\psi_{12}$ is a quadratic polynomial in $t$. So $\psi_{12}\psi_{12}$ is a quartic polynomial, the expression it gives $\sqrt{2}\psi_{10} + \frac{20}{7\sqrt{10}}\psi_{12}$ is a quadratic polynomial...

Comment: Dear @achille hui,  is there something wrong in the following formula? $\psi_{1a}\psi_{1b} = \sum_{c=|a-b|}^{a+b}
\sqrt{2(2a+1)(2b+1)(2c+1)}\begin{pmatrix}a & b & c\\0 & 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}^2 \psi_{1c}$ I am trying to check it for $ \psi_{12}\psi_{14}$. But it is not to equal $\sqrt{\frac{72}{49}}\psi_{12} + \sqrt{\frac{4000}{5929}}\psi_{14} + \sqrt{\frac{2250}{1573}}\psi_{16}$. Could you more explain how to derive it the formula? I can't completely derive it.

Comment: @HD239 The formula is correct, so do the expansion of $\psi_{12}\psi_{14}$. However, I notice the CAS I use (maxima) cannot completely simplify the radicals in RHS of the expansion w/o assistance. Try clearing the radicals in numerator and denominator by hand and try comparing the coefficients numerically. I think you may have same problem.